# Azure Service Bus, How to receive sessions in first in, first out order? (FIFO)

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, fifo

I am currently working with the Azure Service Bus in C#. Problem I am having is messages are not being read in order (first in, first out). I have been trying to use sessions to correct the order the messages are read in. Is there a way to ensure sessions and the messages within sessions are read in first in, first out order?

Comment: Will you have multiple processes/jobs dequeuing the messages ? If so you wont be able to perform FIFO

Comment: @Thomas No the process will synchronous with only one web job dequeuing messages. How we can ensure messages picked up in FIFO without using sessions or can we can all messages in a single session and keep adding to that over time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messages within a single given session are guaranteed to be received in preserved order. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions#session-features):

> Sessions provide concurrent de-multiplexing of interleaved message streams while preserving and guaranteeing ordered delivery.

There are no guarantees across sessions though.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Any links to documentation that explain this?